# How to properly insert date into MYSQL database using php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to store and display date in this format "1.1.1990", (d.m.Y)

I've got a date column in my database with these settings

> TYPE: DATE
>
> Browser display transformation: Date Format(text/plain: Dateformat)
>
> Browser display transformation options: 0,'%j.%n.%Y','local'

My query goes as :

> INSERT INTO table VALUES(STR_TO_DATE('1.1.1990', '%e.%c.%Y'))

So far the query is accepted but a blank field is displayed in database

Only other thing i could get is without using STR_TO_DATE to add a default date as 1.1.1970

Comment: change the data type to varchar

Comment: @vSugumar NNnnooooooooo

Comment: MYSQL stores dates as `YYYY-MM-DD` and thats it. If you want to display your dates as `d.m.Y` then you do that **date conversion** in the applications presentation layer. And of course convert back to MYSQL format to store it on the database

Comment: ___PS___ `phpMyAdmin` is a application writtten in PHP that aids you in maintaing a MYSQL database. The database is MYSQL

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the 2 `Browser display transformation` you mention. Is that MYSQL or something else?

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to set the column in date type
2. You can ensure the date is wellformed: `select STR_TO_DATE('1.1.1990', '%e.%c.%Y');`